# Coping a range of columns to another sheet based on value and multiple onedit running at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I figured this out parts of this but can not for the life of me get the rest to work. I need the following to happen...

1. When edit happens on "Main" tab, I would like all data from columns C, D, Q, R and O to automatically copy values into the coordinating column and update if changed to the "Bubbles" Tab.
2. When edit happens on "Main" tab, I would like all data from columns, D, I, P, Q, and R to automatically copy values into the coordinating column and update if changed to the "Labels" Tab.
3. This is the one I have partly figured out. When edit happens on "Main" tab in column I, I need columns D, I, P, Q, and R to automatically copy values into the coordinating column and update if changed to the coordinating tabs based on the selecting in column I. Example - "web" was selected in column I on the "Main" Tab, I need " F17 : "(in column P on the "Main" Tab) to copy to column B on the "web" tab. Same thing for the other listed columns. But if "BSR/inv." was selected I need the infomation from the columns listed to go to the "BSR/inv." tab.
4. Lastly, when edit happens on "Main" tab in column A, I need columns D, P, Q, and R to automatically copy values into the coordinating column and update if changed to the "Fashion" tab.

Link to Google Sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lxLU8jPz5Ci-azDBbzFgu7Ee_wFsUcPPyybJmWU6oUk/edit?usp=sharing

This is what I have so far that kind of works.

```
function onEdit() {
 var sheetNameToWatch = "Main"; 
 var columnNumberToWatch = 8; 
 var valueToWatch = "web"; 
 var sheetNameToCopyTheRowTo = "web"; 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell(); 
 if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) { 
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToCopyTheRowTo); 
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange); 
 } 
}
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING!!!